# Json based unit testing

Tags: java, json, junit, mockito

We have huge Data Objects which are a little too difficult to manage while creating test cases. In order to test the entire flow we have to create this big object and then assert on it. Sometimes setting up this object takes more effort than the actual testing part. Mock or Spying is also not feasible because that again requires writing more code and becomes difficult to manage with the increase in the number of fields to manage.

I am thinking of keeping the data objects in json files and then load them into memory. This keeps things manageable on our end and also speeds up our development process.

Does any one sees any flaws with this approach or have any suggestions ? We are using Java 8.